# Docker stack deploy with restart_policy throws "Error response from daemon: invalid RestartCondition: "unless-stopped""

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I try to run this with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack-name` I get the error: `Error response from daemon: invalid RestartCondition: "unless-stopped"`

I need both the superservice and the docker container to restart if interrupted. Without the `restart_policy` (using only `--restart unless-stopped` for the container), if I reboot my machine it only restarts the container, not the service. The superservice lets me use service-only docker features (like secrets, config, resources, etc). The container lets me use devices.

Docker [supports the restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy). I also saw [this thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/374), but I'm not sure what to make of it or if it's related. I'm a bit of a Docker noob.

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  superservice:
    image: docker
    command: docker run -it --restart unless-stopped --device=/dev/video0 --volume=/path:/path --name container_name my/image
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      mode: replicated
      restart_policy:
        condition: unless-stopped
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.70'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Docker version 18.05.0-ce, build f150324

Linux raspberrypi 4.14.50-v7+ #1122 SMP Tue Jun 19 12:26:26 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Because `unless-stopped` is not a valid value for restart_policy condition. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy. There's currently not a nice way to manage what you want to do, more details are here: https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1244

Comment: @johnharris85 It doesn't work with `always`, nor `on-failure` either.

Comment: Connor `always` is also not an option, see that link. What does 'not work' mean? `on-failure` should work fine.

Comment: @johnharris85 you are right, I had thought the options were the same for the ones I had referenced for `docker run --restart_policy`. If you want to post an answer basically saying that `docker run` and `docker-compose` have different syntax and what those syntax are I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The restart policies don't map 1:1 from docker compose to docker cli.

## Docker Compose

**docker-compose** policies can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy)

`condition`: One of `none`, `on-failure` or `any` (default: `any`).

```
services:
  service-name:
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

## Docker CLI

**docker cli** policies can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart)

- `no`  Do not automatically restart the container when it exits. This is the default.
- `on-failure[:max-retries]`    Restart only if the container exits with a non-zero exit status. Optionally, limit the number of restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.
- `always`  Always restart the container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.
- `unless-stopped`  Always restart the container regardless of the exit status, including on daemon startup, except if the container was put into a stopped state before the Docker daemon was stopped.

Comment: What is the keyword here - "any" or "always"? Would both of them work?

Comment: Any is for docker compose, always is for docker cli

Comment: That information is in the answer, I understand that it may not be all that clear, how could I edit the answer to make is clearer?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean now. If you ask me, it would have been more clear to me if the font size of "docker-compose" and "docker cli" would have been larger than "Policy Result". That would make it clearer that they are 2 different headings and that "Policy Result" is a part of "docker cli". Sorry, unable to do that from my mobile right now.

Comment: All good I’ll take care of it, thank you for helping me improve it :)

Answer (score 8):

If you deploy as a stack, the restart policy isn't needed, I've even seen it break things in extreme situations (host running out of memory). This is because swarm mode looks at your defined target state, compares it to the current state, and reconciles any differences.

So if your container stops, swarm mode will recreate a new instance regardless of the restart policy. Manually stopping a container will result in a new instance being started, the same as a failure, or even a rolling update.

To manually stop containers managed by swarm mode, you need to push a new target state, where that service has 0 replicas as the new target.

Comment: Very very useful, thank you. Clarifies *why* these tools have different commands, I am going to leave my answer as the accepted answer, because my original question was about what caused the failure in the first place. If you disagree with this, please let me know

Comment: @BMitch , Could you please let us know what can we use if want to limit the number of retries when a container fails in swarm mode ?

Comment: @Deepti-l I'm no aware of any. If it's failing because of an external dependency, you typically want it to keep retrying. And if it falls because it's a broken image, a rollback policy on the deploy is typically what you want.